# Use Mac OS clipboard with Vim

Tags: macos, vim

I'm using Vim (version 7.4) in iTerm (inside a Tmux Session) and I can't seem to access the system's clipboard. I want to be able to copy and paste to and from Vim.

I'm using the Vim that came preinstalled with MacVim ('/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim') and I've tried using `"+y`, `"*y` etc.

When I run `vim --version | grep clipboard` I see that I have `+clipboard` and `-xterm_clipboard`. From what I read online I should be able to use the +,* registers with these settings.

I've tried finding a solution and none of the proposed ones seemed to work.

Is anyone aware of a way to get this to work?

Is there no solution?

Comment: Are you running Vim inside tmux or screen?

Comment: I'm actually using Tmux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to have tmux open shells in an application called [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard).

For example, in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
```

The easiest way to install `reattach-to-user-namespace` is with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).